# three.js texture error reads "GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: Source and destination textures of the draw are the same"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, three.js, textures, chromium

I'm a new developer attempting to use tonemapping, as demonstrated here at Three.js: ( https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_tonemapping ) and I'm unable to avoid a specific error, even when I download source code from threejs.

Quick notes:
1) I am locally using Web Server for Chrome
2) The specific error is "GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: Source and destination textures of the draw are the same"
3) The error repeats over 256 times 
4) The screen is black, and am unable to do anything.

I've looked all over the internet and can't get a clear answer, any feedback would be greatly appreciated. The only clue I have is that WebGL + Chrome might be affecting something with texturing, but I'm not sure.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code you're using? From the error it looks like you're trying to draw to the same render target you're reading from.

Answer (score 4):

The example you mentioned notwithstanding, I have struggled with the same exact error for a week until I have just now finally found a solution after reading the migration guide carefully ([101->102](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide#r101--r102)). `renderer.render()` used to take the render target as the third argument, and now you're supposed to call `setRenderTarget(your_framebuffer)` explicitly before the `render()` call, and what I had missed earlier is that you're also supposed to *unset* the target by calling `setRenderTarget(null)`. That solved my problem. Hope this saves a week to someone else!